# The terminal in IntelljIDEA is not outputting the result as expected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, biginteger

I tried to use BigInteger learn its properties and methods. I write an experiment class to do some basic arithmetic operations. However when I tried to output the result, the terminal seems not working as if there's no output at all. Is there any way I can fix the problem?

Here's my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class exp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BigInteger num1 = new BigInteger("234234234242342342344545546567");
        BigInteger num2 = new BigInteger("344654645635234324435465656332");
        BigInteger num3=num1.multiply(num2);
        BigInteger num4=num1.add(num2);

        System.out.println(num3);
        System.out.println(num4);
    }
}
```

Here's response from Terminal in IDEA:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start the program in IJ (with the green triangle) the output will appear in the "Run" window, not in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! It is solved. I am still learning how to use the IDE.